# Are there no response codes for subscriptions?

Tags: paymill

Paymill:

I'm developing a website which sells subscriptions. Whenever a new customer signs up I do the following:

1. Create a new "client" at Paymill
2. Create a new "payment" (the customers credit card) at Paymill
3. Add a new subscription at Paymill for this "client" using this "payment"

There are no trial periods, so Paymill issues the first transaction immediately. 
But sometimes the first transaction fails, I can see in the cockpit this is due to any of these errors: https://www.paymill.com/pt-pt/documentation-3/reference/api-reference/#document-statuscodes

But how can I know this?  There are no response codes in the returning subscription object (the subscription is set up fine, but the first payment fails).

What have I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are no responsecodes for subscriptions you are right, but you should register webhooks for this. Than you'll be informed if a transaction of this subscription fails and also gets the errorcode. Please have a look for webhooks here https://www.paymill.com/en-gb/documentation-3/reference/api-reference/#webhooks.

We will also make a refactoring for subscription in the first quarter of 2014. Than we'll improve also the responses.

Best,
Christian

Comment: Thanks! 
I don't like the case where the user first is told "subscription is fine" and immediately after "Sorry, I was wrong, the first transaction failed...".  I guess the best way of solving it is to register webhooks for both a successful first transaction and a failed one. Then we could...  
- subscribe the user, but don't tell him anything yet...
- wait for the webhook from the first transaction... if it's possible, tell the user everything is fine, otherwise deny the subscription.

Do you know of code examples of this? Or any other way to solve it?